# How to update MySql data from HTML using PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to update mysql database from html table with php, but when edit the row that i want to update and press the button to update, field that was suposed to updated becomes empty.
Also when i press update i get this notice:
Notice: Undefined index: status in /storage/ssd1/314/2412314/public_html/status3.php on line 174.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$db_host='example';
$db_user='example';
$db_pass='example';
$db_name='example';

 $con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
$STATUS = $_POST['status'];
$PK= $_POST['pkvara'];

$sql = "UPDATE Radionica SET status = '$STATUS' WHERE pkvara = '$PK'";
$retval = mysqli_query($con,$sql );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Status uspešno promenjen\n";
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Radionica")
or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));



while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo '<form action="" method="post">';

  echo '<tr>';

  echo '<td>'.$row['registracija'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['status'].'</td>';
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="sta" value="'.$row['status'].'"><input type="submit" name="update" value="Promeni" /></td>';
   echo'<td><input type="hidden" name="pkvara" value="'.$row['pkvara'].'"></td>';
  echo '</tr>';
  echo '</form>';
  }



mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You have used `$_POST['status']`, but its not spelled correct in form section

Comment: @Sinto thank you i corrected it and now its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**correct this line**

```
echo '<td><input type="text" name="sta" value="'.$row['status'].'"><input type="submit" name="update" value="Promeni" /></td>';
```

**TO**

```
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="STATUS" value="'.$row['status'].'"><input type="submit" name="update" value="Promeni" /></td>';
```

Answer (score 3):

Fix this line and it will work fine.

```
 echo '<td><input type="text" name="status" value="'.$row['status'].'"><input type="submit" name="update" value="Promeni" /></td>';
```